# How to style accordion buttons in a row with the text all opening into the same element

Tags: javascript, css, accordion

I have a bunch of different accordions that, when clicked, expand and display the text below them. That's working fine, but not quite what I want. I'm trying to have the accordion buttons all in a row, and when clicked they expand into an area below. Like:

```
 _   _   _   _
|_| |_| |_| |_|  (unclicked)
 _   _   _   _
|x|_|_|_|_|_|_|  (clicked)
| text of     |  
| accordion   |
|_____________|
```

(excuse the ASCII art.)

Right now what they do is more like this:

```
 _  
|x|___________   (clicked)
| text of     |  
| accordion   |
|_____________|
|_| |_| |_|      <-- other accordion buttons
```

I can't seem to figure out how I can do it the way I'm looking for. I've been messing around with different ways of building accordions (like expandable tables) but I'm at a loss. I couldn't find an example of this style of accordion anywhere, is this possible to do using at least mostly the code I have now?

Here's a Fiddle of where I'm at currently:  https://jsfiddle.net/zeuyhtpw/3/

::edit
included code:

HTML:

```
<button class="accordion">Button 1</button>
<div class="story">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute iruredolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
    eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Button 2</button>
<div class="story">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Button 3</button>
<div class="story">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Button 4</button>
<div class="story">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.story {
  display: none;
}

.accordion {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

JS:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    story = this.nextElementSibling;

    if (story.style.display === "block") {
      story.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      story.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Please include a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked your example a bit https://jsfiddle.net/7szxorcq/17/

HTML

```html
<button class="accordion">Button 1</button>
<button class="accordion">Button 2</button>
<button class="accordion">Button 3</button>
<button class="accordion">Button 4</button>
<div class="story">
  <p>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute iruredolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
    eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div class="story">
  <p>2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div class="story">
  <p>3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div class="story">
  <p>4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
const acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
const stories = document.getElementsByClassName("story");

for (let i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", () => {

    // Show the story we clicked on
    for (let j = 0; j < stories.length; j++) {
        stories[j].style.display = i === j
        ? 'block'
        : 'none';
    }

  });
}
```

Comment: Fabulous, thank you so much! This is excellent, it works perfectly.